# Are there sources for the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild nuget available?

Tags: typescript, msbuild

I can't find the source of the nuget package  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild  and underlaying TypeScript.Tasks.dll.

Are they open sourced?

Comment: Do you need the sources itself? Or do you only want to see the code? For the latter you can simply open it with tools like dotPeek - it's a .NET library

Comment: Ideally I want to see github repo, with history, issues, etc.

Comment: The github repo for TypeScript is [microsoft/TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript) and there is mention of MSBuild in the docs but I can't determine if the source for the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package is in the repo or not.